# Taylor series representation problem

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

During an exam recently, I was asked to prove that $-\ln(2) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n\cdot2^n}$. But after fiddling around a lot, I kept reaching an argument that the sum actually equals $-\ln(1.5)$.

Was the exam incorrect?

Comment: Can you show the details of your reasoning?

Comment: I started with $-\ln(1-x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{x^n}{n}$, and then set $x=-0.5$.

Comment: Thoughts, @corindo?

Comment: The term of the series, as written now, is not defined at $n=0$.  So, is the only change that the series begins at $n=1$?  If so, your calculation is correct.

Comment: @Dr.MV, yeah, that was a typo. It started at $n=1$. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, we have $\ln(2)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac1{n\cdot2^n}~,~$ while the expression they gave is $\ln\dfrac23~.$

Comment: The series is an alternating one.  Or maybe you're saying precisely that.

Answer (score 0):

The Taylor series of $ln(1 + x)$ about zero is the [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series):
$ln(1 + x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{(n+1)}}{n}x^n$

If you set $x = 1$ you'll see there is an extra $\frac{1}{2^n}$ in their answer.